# Silverlight Reflection | GetCurrentMethod with passed parameters

Tags: c#, silverlight, reflection, methodinfo

I want to print the current method call (incl. return value) to the Visual Studio Output like this:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    Func<object, object> ret = (value) =>
    {
#if DEBUG            
        var debug = new StringBuilder();
        debug.Append("MyConverter.Convert([");
        debug.Append(values.Sum(v => (v != null ? v.ToString() : "null") + ',', null, v => v != null ? v.ToString() : "null"));
        debug.Append("], " + targetType.ToString() + ", " + parameter.ToString() + ", " + culture.DisplayName + ") =" + value.ToString() + ";");
        Debug.WriteLine(debug.ToString());
#endif
        return value;
    };

 // [..]
}
```

I'm using this sometimes to achieve more informations (e.g. from a Converter as shown here) while debugging. However, that's just a roundabout way.

Is there any way to do it more flexible? Something like GetCurrentArguments (from MethodInfo)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using it for debugging there is an option using the [StackTrace and StackFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.getframe%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) To get the current method name, but you wont get the arguments, and there is a severe performance penalty.